# Can Memcached limit "write per second" and "read per second" on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, memcached

I need to reduce the value of "write per second" and "read per second" on MySQL (this is for statistics: total views of post).

Can Memcached doing this job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Memcache cannot control traffic. What you can do is MySQL cluster with load balancer.

Memcache is accelerator for MySQL with key-value store

Answer (score 0):

Memcached doesn't have any such controls. You probably need some form of proxy server to sit in between your program calling MySQL and MySQL server itself. Check out MySQL Proxy:

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy

Lua is a pretty straight forward language and you can probably implement exactly what you're looking for.